# How to access a private network on Quest2's Android 12

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I am trying to connect MetaQuest2's Android 12 to a Wi-Fi network that does not broadcast SSID, but the connection button is not enabling. The certificate installation was successful and the proxy settings are correct, so what could be the cause?

Comment: What is your definition of a private network? A wifi network that does not broadcast it's SSID? But usually you don't need certificate for a Wifi. Certificates are mostly used in combination with a network that sues  802.11x radius authentication. So please edit your question and describe in detail what type of network you are trying to connect to and what requirement this network has.

Comment: This Wi-Fi network is a company network with a "WPF/WPF2-Enterprise" authentication.

Comment: I was able to press the connection button by changing the save location of the certificate file, but I can't connect. Am I doing something wrong with the installation of the certificate itself?